# ActiveRecord Group by statement not converting to Time.zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, time, timezone

I use the query below to give me a count of checkins broken down by day.

```
Checkin.select("date(created_at) as calendar_day, count(*) as total_checkins").where("user_id = ? AND created_at > ?", user.id, 28.days.ago).group("date(created_at)").order("date(created_at)")
```

Example output:

[image: example output]

The issue I'm facing is that this query is in UTC and does not convert to the Time.zone (PST) I have set in my application.rb file under config.time_zone. In the example above the last two checkins should be under "2012-07-30".

I know that with other queries this conversion works fine. For example with:

```
Checkin.last.created_at # Returns in PST
```

So it must be something about the complexity of the query above. I'm guessing it might be the select statement. How could I write the above to account for the configured timezone?

Comment: The issue is that you're grouping by date in SQL. The DB doesn't know you want a different time zone. Not sure how to do this though ...

Comment: Take a look at the question here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274375/ror-postgresql-timezone-group-by-not-working-on-heroku

The problem seems that Rails doesn't create columns with Time zone support in postgres.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looks like this can't be fixed as-is without going into schema.rb and manually changing the 'created_at' and 'updated_at' fieldtypes. I'm wary of doing that. Perhaps there is another way for me to write my query where the "grouping" actually happens in rails?

Comment: Well I guess you could do the grouping back in Rails, but if the Data set grows, it'd become crazy and would eat a lot of memory since you'd have to instantiate all AR objects to be able to group them by date ... if I were I'd just display that stats are displayed based on the UTC timezone, or switch the DB to your local timezone if you only work with one timezone (unlikely)

Comment: My guess is that the getter converts it to the right time zone. Have you tried <your-massive-query>.first.created_at to see if it gives you the right time-zone?

Comment: I ended up just doing the grouping in Rails. I'm only looking at about 30 objects max as I do this one month at a time, so hoping its not too much of a performance hit. @AJcodez haven't tried, but as the query converts to a date, I'm assuming that the timestamp has already been dropped.

Answer (score 4):

I am doing something of the same kind (although I am grouping by the minute)... using the code below works right for me...

```
Time.zone.utc_to_local(DateTime.parse(@checkin[:calendar_day]))
```

I do this for each item in the group and then pass an array hash to the view layer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue trying to group activity by day (this is for a highcharts graph).  I would have liked to do something like this:

```
# Didn't work
counts = Event.where(:created_at => start_date..end_date.end_of_day)
.group("DATE(created_at)").count

return (start_date..end_date).map{ |d| counts[d] }
```

but start_date and end_date were in my local timezone, and the DATE function was in UTC.  Instead I did this in Ruby.

```
counts = Event.where(:created_at => start_date..end_date.end_of_day)
.pluck(:id, :created_at)
.group_by{|obj| obj[1].to_date}

return (start_date..end_date).map{ |d| counts[d].try(:size) }
```